# Why async/await function performed last one although it called at the first

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

although there’re a lot of similar topics here but I tried a ton of suggestions and I couldn’t found the answer.

In my node app I want to get a string value (userType) from an API through a async/await function (getUserType)

After that I want to process this result through another function (authResult) so:
I called the two functions in this order:

getUserType();

authResult();

but the 2nd function (authResult) performed before the asynchronous function (getUserType) so I can’t get a correct result

in other words: the async function always executed after all other functions.

Here is the calling order:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  callAsyncFunc();
  authResult();
})
```

and here's async functions:

```js
let usertype ='before_call';

async function callAsyncFunc() {
 usertype = await getUserType();
 console.log(usertype);
}

async function getUserType() {
 let result  =
 (await fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/usertype', {
      headers: {
        'content-type' : 'application/json'
      },

      method: 'POST',
    })).text()

    console.log(result); //show: is_admin
    return result;
}
```

and here's the authentication function that performed first but I want it to performed after the async function ends

```js
function authResult() {
     console.log(usertype); // show: before_call
     
     switch (usertype) {
       case 'admin':
         console.log('user role is admin');
         break;
     }
}
```

```
console.log print:
 // before_call :this should be the 2nd
 // is_admin :this should be the 1st
```

Any suggestion please!

Comment: Try turning the function `DOMContentLoaded', () => {` into an async one, and then awaiting `callAsyncFunc`

Comment: You're not waiting for the async functions to complete before calling `authResult()`.

Comment: @Barmar  **fast and useful solution** , the 2nd one has resolved it: callAsyncFunc().then(() => authResult());... Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

Either make the function `async` so you can use `await`

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', async () => {
  await callAsyncFunc();
  authResult();
})
```

or use `.then()`

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  callAsyncFunc().then(() => authResult());
})
```